# Virtual IP Address

Tags: windows, networking, ip, lan

I am developing an application related to networking . Its prerequisite is that the machine must have an ip address to function properly.

When i am on my home network , my machine gets the IP address through DHCP present on my network. However, when my machine is in stand alone mode e.g. while travelling i can not have an ip address and the status is LAN DISCONNECTED.

Is there a workaround so that i can get an ip address or virtual ip address in standalone mode?

I have already tried configuring with loopback address and other ip address.

Can I do it by installing a dhcp server on my machine? My system uses WINXP?

Network card: BroadcomNetxtreme 57XX gigabit ethernet.

I strongly feel that the application details have nothing to do with it. Since, when the machine has an ip address it starts working properly.

Still i am open to ideas.

Comment: What's the problem using the loopback address `127.0.0.1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I advise you to work inside a virtual machine, and then assign a virtual IP and vitual MAC of your convenience. You can use Virtual Box or VMWare.